# Code a clock speed up calculator

Tags: javascript, php, performance, clock

Ok, so I have a timer that was written for me that runs a relay. I have it setup so that it runs at 1.1667x faster than a normal speed clock. So it runs like that for however long I need it to.

HOWEVER- The computer crashed and although I know when I started the clock at that rate, I do not know what it would be now, a month later. So I do not know what the time and date would be on in that sped up clock time computer.

What I want to do is write a PHP, Javascript, or other program that I can use to input the start date, the time, and the acceleration multiplier. Then have it tell me what the time and date would be today if I started the clock, say on February 1st at 1.1667x.

Any thoughts on how I might do about doing that? I have some skills in JS, PHP, jQuery. But the mathmatics behind this are completely eluding me.

Comment: it's just basic  math: two trains leave the station at the same time. one travels at 1.6667x the speed of the other. if the faster train travelled 50miles, how far did the slower/realtim train go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php

```
$startdate = strtotime('2014-02-01 2:20 PM'); 
$rightnow = time();
//get seconds between
$diff = $rightnow - $startdate;
//calc how many seconds should be, 
$timeshouldbe = $diff * 1.1667 + $startdate;
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $timeshouldbe);
```

Comment: Does this allow me to add the exact time, not just date?

Comment: It would return March 18, 2014, 10:59 am on running the script.

Comment: I mean to the start time, so instead of 12:00am on feb 01, say 3:30pm on feb 1.

Comment: strtotime will take about any date/time you throw at it. I edited answer with added time.
http://us2.php.net/strtotime

Comment: Great. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That's a very strange application you have there...but the math is quite easy.  I'll use JavaScript to demonstrate.  First you need the number of milliseconds that have elapsed in real-world time:

```
var divergence = new Date(2014, 1, 1);  // 0 = Jan, 1 = Feb, etc.

var realElapsed = Date.now() - divergence.getTime();
```

Then you just apply your multiplier:

```
var speedyElapsed = realElapsed * 1.1667;
```

Then construct a date for that:

```
var speedyDate = new Date(divergence.getTime() + speedyElapsed);
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I hope this is right lol seems way to easy. It completely eluded me.